# Enable roles without (or with a dummy) Role Provider

Tags: asp.net, .net, authorization, roleprovider, asp.net-roles

I'm following [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;311495) in which is described how to assign roles to users when theiy log-in using forms authentication:

```
public void Application_AuthenticateRequest( Object src , EventArgs e )
{
   if (!(HttpContext.Current.User == null))
   {
      if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms" )
      {
      System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity id;
      id = (System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
      String[] myRoles = new String[2];
      myRoles[0] = "Manager";
      myRoles[1] = "Admin";
      HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id,myRoles);
      }
   }
}
```

I put the role logic in the event handler, so I basically don't need a role provider. Nonetheless, in order to run this, appears that I must enable Role Provider in `web.config`. Sadly, if I just put:

```
<roleManager enabled="true"/>
```

it results in runtime errors related to a failed connection to the SQL server, like if I chose `AspNetSqlRoleProvider` as Role Provider.

What should I do to have roles working this way? How can I choose to use no role provider, or how should I implement a dummy one (if it makes any sense)?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. I don't believe you need to enable a role manager to do this. What happens if you don't enable the role provider in web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to enable `roleManager` in web.config - after all, people used to use roles with .NET 1.x before roleManager came along.

One thing that `roleManager` will do for you that you haven't done in your code is set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to `HttpContext.Current.User`.  If you're relying on this (e.g. using `PrincipalPermissionAttribute`), then you need to add this:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Otherwise, I'd expect it to work: what symptoms are you seeing that makes you think it isn't working?

As for implementing a dummy `RoleProvider`, it's easy enough: for example see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx).

You only need to implement the `GetRolesForUser` and `IsInRole` methods; the other methods can simply throw `NotSupportedException`.